# Add a method to a string variable's prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

Expected: When a variable is created using `createGreetable` it should have an additional property `greet` set by `greetable(text)`. The usual `string` methods should still be callable on this variable.

What I Tried:

```js
const greetablePrototype = {
  greetable: function(greeting) {
    this.greet = `${greeting}, ${ this.valueOf() }!`
  }
}

function createGreetable(str) {
  const result = new String(str);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(result, greetablePrototype)
  return result;
}

const t = new createGreetable("world");
t.greetable("hello");
console.log(t.greet);

console.log(t.length);
```

Output:

```
hello, [object String]!
5
```

Expected Output:

```
hello, world!
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the string class:

```js
class Greetable extends String {
  greet (greeting) {
    return `${greeting}, ${this}!`;
  }
}

const g = new Greetable('world');
g.greet('hello'); // hello, world!
g.length // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A few modifications to your code were needed to get it to work as intended:

1. Adding `this.length` in the `greetable` prototype function to update the string length each time (remember this is a [string object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)).
2. Changing the `const result` line to `this.greet` in the constructor function, setting the prototype of `this` to the `greetablePrototype` as intended, then returning the instance of our object `return this`.

```js
const greetablePrototype = {
  greetable: function(greeting) {
    this.greet = `${greeting}, ${this.greet}!`
    this.length = this.greet.length;
  }
}

function createGreetable(str) {
  this.greet = String(str);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(this, greetablePrototype)
  return this;
}

const t = new createGreetable("world");
t.greetable("hello");
console.log(t.greet);
console.log(t.length);
```

Comment: `greet` is taking over the sting object. The value and length should still correspond to the string with which the variable is initialized with. Is there a way to make this work otherwise?

Comment: I figured I would suggest a potential solution different from Jared's answer. I wasn't sure if extending the String class was what you were looking for, but it does provide the best result overall.

Answer (score 1):

```
const greetableProto =  {
    greet: function greet(greeting) {
        return `${greeting}, ${this}!`;
    }
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(greetableProto, String.prototype);

function createGreetable(str) {
  const result = new String(str);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(result, greetableProto);
  return result
}


const g2 = createGreetable('Mark')
console.log(g2.greet('Hello'))
```